# How can I view how my Java code once converted into binary?

Tags: java, bytecode

I want to get a view of my code once it is converted into binary after I hit Run

```
public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

Is there any IDE Available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile your HelloWorld.java, you'll get a HelloWorld.class file, and that's the binary. If you use e.g. the Eclipse IDE, you'll typically find these files in a "bin" folder.

Take the hex/binary viewer of your choice, and look into that file. You'll probably find [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) useful when analysing the file contents.

Comment: Or run `javap -p -c` (optionally add `-l -v` to taste) on the compiled class (either in a file or in a jar) for a convenient decode. But you'll still need to _understand_ the JVM spec, which BTW has been updated, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html .